# Загрузка файла большого размера на сервер

Tags: java, spring-boot, download

Клиент-серверное приложение. Клиент (моб. телефон) отправляет на сервер огромный файл весом 2 и более гб, у клиента может сесть аккумулятор, но при включении телефона и приложения отправка файла должна продолжиться. Вопрос: как это реализовать на беке?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если файл расценивать как стрим, то в принципе можно сделать всё, что угодно, в том числе и передавать его частями. Идея следующая:

- Человек начинает загружать файл на сервер.
- Загрузка прерывается.
- Через какое-то время, человек хочет возобновить отправку. Клиент спрашивает сервер, сколько байт уже было получено, и отправляет только то, что осталось.

Важно, что именно сервер должен говорить, сколько байт он уже получил. Число байт, которые клиент послал здесь не важны, так как между моментом, когда клиент что-то послал, и моментом, когда сервер это записал, может произойти много чего нехорошего.

Если клиент, настоящее ПО, то я думаю всё понятно. Если это обычный веб-сайт, то файл нужно [открыть сначала на стороне клиента](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298948/240613) и уже с JavaScript посылать те байты, которые нужно.

На сервере, очень важно активировать stream upload, иначе сервер не станет записывать файл, если отправка прервалась. Но я полагаю вы уже это активировали, если работаете с файлами по два гигабайта.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала приложение отправляет на сервер размер файла, а сервер создаёт пустой файл указанного размера и назначает ему какой-нибудь id.

Затем приложение отправляет на сервер часть файла (например 1МБ) с указание id файла и смещением от начала. Сервер открывает файл, записывает полученный блок в нужное место и запоминает переданный размер.

При повторном запуске приложение спрашивает у сервера сколько байт файла у него есть и продолжает передавать по частям с указанного места.

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать наподобие [Amazon S3 MPU](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html):

- сначала проверяем - ListMultipartUploads
- если еще нет, создаем - CreateMultipartUpload
- если уже да, то проверяем какие части уже загружены - ListParts
- потому загружаем недостающие части (можно параллельно) - UploadPart
- когда все засти загружены, завершаем - CompleteMultipartUpload
- или же, если по какой то причине надо откатить, обрываем - AbortMulipartUpload